# Jmeter: Reuse or link HTTP Request Samplers in different Loop Controllers

Tags: jmeter

I have a Thread Group and in it I have several Loop Controllers that we understand as scenarios. Each Loop Controllers contains one or more HTTP Request Samplers to be executed when the Loop runs.
Now I would like to re-use or link these HTTP Request Samplers in different Loop Controllers, so that I don't have to have multiple copies of the same request.
Example:
- Loop Controller: Start page
--- HTTP Request: Load Start page
- Loop Controller: Contact form page
--- HTTP REquest: Load Contact form page
- Loop Controller: Clickpath Start-Contact form
--- >> HOW TO REFERENCE HTTP Requests from above? <<

Is this possible with jmeter?
Thanks in advance for your insights

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that users know it is usable. Thx

Answer (score 3):

To do that put what you want to reuse in a Test Fragment.

And then everywhere you want to use it, use a Module Controller:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK - no. You will have to copy and paste these HTTP Request in different scenarios.